# How to refresh data with angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a simple page where i can add a value into a database (which contains only Id and a value). I would like also to display all values from the database into the page.

The code works well, i can add and display informations, but i got a problem.

The problem is that i'm stuck into the "loading". In order to display i have to select my component page, then go onto an other page, and finally go back onto my page, then it works.
Notice that when i put the method "getData()" without using a service it display correctly. So i think my problem is due to my service, but i don't understand why.

Here is my html code :

```
<h1> data to display : </h1>

<p *ngIf="!data"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<table class='table' *ngIf="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataToDisplay of data">
      <td>{{ dataToDisplay.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ dataToDisplay.nom }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>add Data : </h1>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ngModel>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="f.invalid">Enregistrer</button>
</form>
```

And the .ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValuesService } from '../Services/values.service';
import { Person } from '../models/values-interface';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
/** test component*/
export class TestComponent {
  /** test ctor */
  public data: any;
  constructor(private monService: ValuesService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.monService.getData();
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const name = form.value['name'];
    this.monService.postData(name);
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :
The problem was that my service must return an observable (without subscribe) as follow :

```
    export class ValuesService {
  values: any;
  public baseUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44343';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postData(data: string): Observable<any> {
    var formated_data: Person = { nom: data };
    return this.http.post<Person>(this.baseUrl + '/api/values', formated_data, httpOptions);
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/values');
  } 
}
```

Then my component must subscribe to this observable as follow :

```
    export class TestComponent {
  /** test ctor */
  public data: any ;
  public baseUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44343';

  constructor(private monService: ValuesService, private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.monService.getData().subscribe(result => this.data = result);
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const name = form.value['name'];
    this.monService.postData(name).subscribe(result => this.data.push(result));
  }
}
```

Notice that the function this.data.push(result) is to add the posted value to the actual page. 
My controler is defined as follow (C# .net core) :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostValues([FromBody]Values data)
{
    _context.Values.Add(data);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your data is only refreshed from the back-end when your component first loads on ngOnInit() function. If  you want to get a fresh results set from your back-end after adding a new item, you will have to explicitly refresh it again by calling

```
 this.data = this.monService.getData();
```

again.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fix the problem.
I got an issue with my service i guess. 
I have updated the question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your ValuesService should return Observable or Promise, then you should check if operation is succeeded and so on, simplified version:

```
postData(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.strigify(data));
}
```

then in your Component:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const name = form.value['name'];
    this.monService.postData(name).subscribe(() => this.data = this.monService.getData());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I got an error 400 when i use your post method.
Also, it doesn't fix the first problem that data doesn't displayed on the first time i call the component.